# Amplitude of voltage from centre tap rectifier?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current

Should be the amplitude of voltage obtained from a centre tap transformer be about half if not rectified? Because in centre tap the potential difference for each half cycle is taken a cross only half of the secondary of the transformer. If not rectified then we are taken across the full length of the secondary, since the length is reduced to half so the potential difference in rectifier.As can be seen from the image potential difference is maximum between two ends of the secondary .

$${Any\ Help\ Is\ Greatly\ Appreciated}$$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the *open circuit* voltage of the center tap of a transformer secondary is the average of the two ends of the secondary.

Once way to visualize this is to consider each turn of wire in the secondary as a separate winding, just that they all happen to be connected in series.  Each turn looks like a AC voltage source.  N turns in series will have N times the voltage of one turn.  You don't need to invoke magnetic flux, the primary, or greek letters to see this.

Comment: Yeah, if the voltage is average then why we consider efficiency of full wave rectifier twice of half wave, where in half wave voltage is taken between the two end? I want to say that in half wave rectifier only half of the cycle is rectified so the efficiency is nearly half and in full wave rectifier voltage is half so the efficiency of full wave rectifier should also be half and equal to half wave rectifier!!!

Comment: @JM97: You seem to be confusing several concepts.  You originally asked about voltage, but now you are talking about efficiency within the context of a larger circuit.  That's a totally different discussion.

Comment: Actually I wanted to prove that efficiency would be same for both by the above argument

Comment: @JM97: Again, voltage and efficiency are two completely different things.  And, efficiency of what exactly.  Power out to power in? Power per cost? Space per power?  In any case, all those are off the topic of this question, which is about voltage out of a tapped secondary.